# divisible problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

Find maximum n such that $2^n$ divides $2559^{2^{13}}​-2557^{2^{13}}​$

Comment: Did you mean *divides* where you typed *is divisible by*?

Comment: Might help to apply binomial theorem to $(a+2)^n-a^n$.

Comment: Using [Lifting the Exponent](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/)

Comment: Our policy on contest math questions requires an explanation of the source. Basically we want to make sure that it is not a currently running contest. Many of us have been involved in contests, and want to protect their integrity.

Comment: @Jyrki I don't see any claims here that this is a contest question. Were some comments deleted?

Comment: @BillDubuque That is based on the OP's choice of tags only. I didn't vote to close this, but somebody else did. Presumably for "lack of context" or its current substitute. Questions about contest problems often require "other type of context" (given that the nature of the beast is such that an asker may have difficulties getting started).

Comment: @Jyrki Likely many questions tagged contest-math are simply practice problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [Lifting the Exponent](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/), we know that:
$$n=v_2({2559}^{2^{13}}-{2557}^{2^{13}})=v_2(2559-2557)+v_2(2^{13})+v_2(2559+2557)-1\\=v_2(2)+13+v_2(5116)-1=1+13+2-1=15$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with lifting the exponent. Is it the same you would get by using "telescoping factorizations" such as
$$(x^8-y^8)=(x-y)(x+y)(x^2+y^2)(x^4+y^4)?$$ Here obviously with $2^{13}$ in place of $8$. Observing that most of the factors here are $\equiv2\pmod4$ when $x,y$ are odd. The problem being that I didn't see a proof in the link you gave.